# Error while importing the model data into elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, kibana-6

I want the index data in Kibana to be updated from my database, hence I am doing `Model.import` command. Ex: `Post.import` and the index name inside the Kibana is `posts_development`.

I am getting the following error, while doing `Post.import` inside the Rails console.

> {"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is
>   not supported","status":406}

Many SO threads say tohave the same versions, I tried converting the versions to be the same for the elasticsearch gem and the elasticsearch services. (6.0.1).

> I am using **searchkick 1.3.0** gem in rails and it inturn uses
>   **elasticsearch 6.0.1** and my **Kibana version is also 6.0.1**

I am still getting the above error while trying to import the data to Kibana.

Any help is appreciated.

Also , please let me know if any more details is required.

Comment: It seems to be some underlying issue with the client that is not properly setting `Content-Type` header. It should have `application/json` value.

Comment: Is there a way to set this in Rails. I am using Searchkick gem.. when I try to do `Post.import` , I am getting `@response=#<Tire::HTTP::Response:0x007fc2aa547058 @body="{\"error\":\"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported\",\"status\":406}", @code=406` .

Comment: Are you sure, that this is performed by `searchkick` gem, not `tire` (as the response object's class suggests)? If it's `tire`, drop it because it's long outdated and IIRC it does not fully support Elasticsearch 2+.

Comment: Thanks @MichałSzajbe for your time and discussion. Got this resolved by downgrading the elasticsearch service version to 2.4, which is not equal to the Kibana version and the elasticsearch gem version. I am not sure if it may cause trouble later. Going forward with the development to explore.